# Is there such a thing as ωth-order infinitary logic?

Tags: logic, infinity

I've seen references to ωth-order logic sprinkled (sparsely) throughout my studies, though what properties this has compared to and contrasted with *n*th-order logics I wouldn't be able to tell you (I'm still learning what the difference is between first- and second-order logic, for example).

It seems, from searches I've run on Google, that basic infinitary logics can be/are first-order (maybe even zeroth-order?). Is that true? Or would they automatically count as at least ωth-order? By the definitions I've seen of αth-order logics generally, it doesn't seem to me as if these two infinitary determinations of logic are automatically correlated as such, but I wouldn't be surprised to discover that I was totally wrong, here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Infinitary logics like L(1,) (the simplest and best-behaved of the bunch) and higher-order logics like second-order logic extend first-order logic in different directions. Infinitary logics extend first-order logic essentially by allowing "longer" formulas in controlled ways. On the other hand, roughly speaking the *order* of a logic refers to the sorts of things it can quantify over: e.g. can it quantify over merely *elements* of the structure, or *subsets* of the structure as well, or even more complicated configurations (e.g. sets-of-subsets, which would take us into third-order)?

Neither subsumes the other: for example, by a simple counting argument there is an L(1,)-sentence with no second-order equivalent (although [there are some surprising subtleties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373792/is-there-an-infinitary-sentence-which-is-absolutely-not-second-order-expressib)), and one can also show with more work that there is a second-order sentence with no L(1,)-equivalent - for example, there is a second-order formula true in exactly those structures whose cardinality is a successor cardinal, and you can't do that with an infinitary sentence.

- Incidentally it turns out that infinitary logics are **vastly better behaved** in general than even second-order logic, but this gets a bit technical.

Now to your question proper, we **definitely can** have something like th order L(1,), call it "L(1,)" for brevity. Basically, we just combine the syntactic operations of both the "L(1,)-part" and the "th-order" part! So for example we could have a disjunction of infinitely many clauses, with the nth clause being an nth-order first-order sentence.